# How to use int* in a struct

Tags: pointers, struct, int

I got a struct and an initializing function like following:

```
struct someStruct {
    int* b, r;  // r is a pointer to an integer in b
};

someStruct* init_struct(size_t size) {
    someStruct* p = (someStruct*) malloc(sizeof(someStruct));
    p->b = (int*) malloc(size);
    p->b[0] = 16;
    p->r = &p->b;  // Here's the error, why?
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be without ampersand like `p->r = p->b`
Why are you dereferencing p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the `r` field is an integer, not a pointer to an integer ! Also, &(p->b) is a *pointer to a pointer to an integer* (`int**`). You need to define your struct like this if you want r to be pointing a integer in the b array :

```
struct someStruct {
    int *b, *r;
}
```

And assign the r pointer by dereferencing an **element** of b (`int`), not the pointer itself (`int*`):

```
p->r = &(p->b[0]);
```

Or don't dereference b at all if you want to point to `b[0]` :

```
p->r = p->b;
```

Comment: Thanks, the fault was that I didn't made the "r" a pointer too. In future I should write the "*" beside the variable not beside the datatype. It makes it a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Its been like 15 days since i looked at C, but i have this weird feeling that your error line should look more like:

```
p->r = &(p->b);
```

Its just a hunch though.  I dont have time to test at this second.

That way it is saying that you will store the address of the b* into p->r

But with pointers, they hold addresses, not the dereferenced value, so you could do

```
p->r = p->b;
```

unless you are trying to get the address of where the point is, and not the address of where the pointer points.

Answer (score 0):

`int* b, r;` - This statment means `b` is a pointer to int variable and `r` is an int variable. If you want to declare r also as pointer to int variable you have to follow any one of the way mentioned below.

1st way

```
int* b = NULL;
int* a = NULL;
```

2nd way

```
int *b = NULL, *a = NULL;
```

3rd way

```
typedef int* INT_POINTER;
INT_POINTER a = NULL, b = NULL;
```

Dont use macro `#define` instead of `typedef`

Best way is to use `typedef`, to avoid confusion.

and also assignment statement should be like `p->r = &(p->b[0]);`